# Race Conditions With Trigger After Insert In MySql

Tags: mysql, triggers, race-condition

I have a mysql trigger that I have a concern about having noticed some "unsynced" data in my db after deploying the trigger to my production site a few days ago.

I have simplified my code for the purposes of posting here.

There are 3 tables:

**score** table: ID, UserID, Score, GameID (users enter a score each time they play a game, they can play the same game a number of times)

**score_summary** table: ID, UserID, GameID, SummaryValue (this table keeps a running score for each user for each game)

**game_summary** table: ID, GameID, SummaryValue (this table keeps a running overall score for each game)

When a game score is entered for a user into the score table, the trigger is there to update the user's running total score (SummaryValue) in table score_summary and also to update the game_summary table for given GameID.

```
CREATE TRIGGER scores_insert_trigger AFTER INSERT ON scores
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

    UPDATE scores_summary
    SET SummaryValue=SummaryValue + NEW.Score 
    WHERE UserID=NEW.UserID
    SELECT ROW_COUNT() INTO rowCount;
    IF (rowCount=0) THEN
        INSERT INTO scores_summary
        (UserID, GameID, SummaryValue)
        VALUES
        (NEW.UserID, NEW.GameID, NEW.Score);
    END IF;

    UPDATE game_summary
    SET SummaryValue=SummaryValue + NEW.Score 
    WHERE GameID=NEW.GameID
    SELECT ROW_COUNT() INTO rowCount;
    IF (rowCount=0) THEN
        INSERT INTO game_summary
        (GameID, SummaryValue)
        VALUES
        (NEW.GameID, NEW.Score);
    END IF;
END;
```

My concerns are with regards to the trigger running into a race condition if a number of users enter scores at the same time - in particular for the update of the game_summary when no scores exist for the particular game - if two users attempt this at the same time, they will both get rowCount=0 and will then both do an insert?

Are my concerns justified and if so is there anything I can do about this?

Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to provide an answer for my particular situation.

My update statements are atomic updates which means mysql engine handles any potential race conditions.

To avoid race condition on insert, I have opted for ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE which will again be atomic and will avoid two or more threads causing multiple rows being created.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Uhm, if you end up with using `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` then you have added unique key (or primary which is unique). `If you specify ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, and a row is inserted that would cause a duplicate value in a UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY, MySQL performs an UPDATE of the old row.` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Answer (score 1):

Just create `UNIQUE` index on `game_summary.GameID` or make it primary key.

`UNIQUE` index will prevent adding duplicate row by second user. Whole transaction will fail and will be rollbacked so your application need to handle this exception e.g. after failing try again before giving up. The disadvantage of this solution is that in very busy environment this will lead to many collisions and many rollbacks but you can be sure there won't be any duplicate rows.

You can also use [GET_LOCK(str, timeout)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_get-lock) function to gain exclusive lock for given `GameID`, update or insert value, and finally [RELEASE_LOCK(str)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_release-lock) so next user can update scores too. This could be much more efficient in some situations but you need to check that.

Comment: My problem is I have other columns in there (like categoryId, seasonId etc) which I have excluded to simplify my question, so creating a unique index on each of those columns won't work.

With Get_lock and Release_lock, what happens if two or more processes attempt to do operations on the same value? One of them locks it, does the insert while the others wait? Is there any data lost if the second process attempts to access the data, sees that it s locked and moves on? or does it wait - do I have to fail and try again?

Comment: You can add unique key on multiple columns so if there should be only one row for same gameId, categoryId and seasonId (e.g. There could be exactly one row for  gameId=1, categoryId=2 and seasonId=3) then add one unique key on all three columns: `ALTER TABLE game_summary ADD UNIQUE ( 
 gameId, categoryId, seasonId
 );` You really should consider adding such key as it helps to keep data consistent even if you make mistakes in your application logic.

Comment: With locking mechanism you still need to figure out what makes a row in game_summary unique (there could be only one gameID=3 in game_summary? Or there could be only one row with gameId=1, categoryId=2 and seasonId=3?) so you can create and pass proper string to `GET_LOCK`. About `GET_LOCK(str, timeout)` - if it can't acquire lock on given string `str` then it waits given `timeout` before giving up. Just read manual.

Comment: You haven't said whether other processes need to poll the locked resource until it's released or not.

I am sure there is a more elegant solution to this issue.

Comment: No. GET_LOCK tries to acquire lock for `timeout` seconds before returning false. So if other process releases lock before `timeout` it will have again chance to acquire lock. However firstly I still recommend to use one unique key on one or several table columns.